# installing onos fails in osx and ubuntu

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, buck, onos

I'm new in onos and I am having trouble installing it. I follow the instructions from [building onos](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/test/Building+ONOS). However, if I install it in a ubuntu 16.04 machine, it fails and output error as

```
BUILD FAILED: Couldn't get dependency '//apps/acl:onos-apps-acl-oar' of target '//tools/package:onos-package':
Parse error for build file /home/chao/onos/apps/acl/BUCK:   File "/home/chao/onos/buck-out/tmp/buck_run.OxbVbj/buck_python_program1045177675292026939/buck.py", line 1417, in process_with_diagnostics
diagnostics=diagnostics)
  File "/home/chao/onos/buck-out/tmp/buck_run.OxbVbj/buck_python_program1045177675292026939/buck.py", line 1316, in process
implicit_includes=self._implicit_includes)
  File "/home/chao/onos/buck-out/tmp/buck_run.OxbVbj/buck_python_program1045177675292026939/buck.py", line 1255, in _process_build_file
implicit_includes=implicit_includes)
  File "/home/chao/onos/buck-out/tmp/buck_run.OxbVbj/buck_python_program1045177675292026939/buck.py", line 1178, in _process
exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/chao/onos/apps/acl/BUCK", line 18, in <module>
web_context = '/onos/v1/acl',
  File "/home/chao/onos/bucklets/onos.bucklet", line 307, in osgi_jar_with_tests
**kwargs)
  File "/home/chao/onos/bucklets/onos.bucklet", line 171, in osgi_jar
onos_jar(
NameError: global name 'onos_jar' is not defined
```

I have found a discussion relate to this problem. Someone says that I have to install buck by onos-buck instead of installing it from it's git repos. However, I've never install buck. The only thing I do is running those scripts in onos repos.

In the other side, I also tried install it on a macbook. It failed with this message.

```
BUILD FAILED: Google APIs not found in     /Users/George/Library/Android/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-23/libs.
```

Please run '/Users/User/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk' and select both 'SDK Platform' and 'Google APIs' under Android (API 23)

However, if I run /Users/User/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk, it says that this command is deprecated, which is

---

The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

---

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you're working from are on a 'test' wiki, which isn't as up to date as the wiki that relates to the current development version of ONOS. I'd suggest you try working from this [Developer Quick Start](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Developer+Quick+Start). Note the text 'ONOS' in that hyperlink where the one you provided has 'test'.

I've installed, built and run ONOS on Ubuntu 16.04, so it does work.